# Specifying selector of the element to which we are attaching jQuery event

Tags: jquery

In jQuery when we want to use live event (i.e. listening event that bubbles up), we write something like:

```
$dom_element.on('click', some_selector_here, handler);
```

Now imagine that we want the click to be triggered if and only if $dom_element also satisfies some selector test. Of course, we can always write:

```
$dom_element.on('click', some_selector_here, function() {
    if ($dom_element.is(yet_another_selector) {
         //do the job!
         ...
    } 
}
```

I want to ask is there is a way to set this selector not in handler logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few different ways to filter your selectors down in jquery.  `.find()`, `.not`, or even filters within the selector itself, such as `:nth-child`, `:even`.  If you really want to get creative though, jquery allows you to write your own filter using `.filter()`.

I've found you can get pretty creative with this.  Then, you just modify your code above like so:

```
$dom_element.filter(yet_another_selector).on('click', some_selector_here, handler);
```

This allows you to use functions, or closures, in both your filter and your handler, modifying as neccesary as your events bubble.

Documentation for `.filter()`: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: that's because you used the filter for `:not()` incorrectly, forked and modified: http://jsfiddle.net/uRzkJ/1/

Comment: @Wow, my bad, a  typo, but in any way I had not realized that filter can be used this `lazy` way.

Comment: I get that feeling just about anytime I use jQuery! :)

Comment: sorry, but I nevertheless looks like you are wrong - this is not something like lazy or live listening - checkout this example (hope no typos for now ))) - http://jsfiddle.net/uRzkJ/2/

Comment: you're killin me bro!  Your problem this time is the selector within your `:not()`.  `.awaiting` selects the `ul` not the `li` which is what your function runs on.  I forked and updated again: http://jsfiddle.net/gEgfG/1/